# How to make bookmarks save Background color of Button/shape?

Tags: powerbi

I have tried everything but I can't make the bookmark preserve different colors... Whether I click bookmark 1 and boomark 2 I see the same, and even if I update it doesnt save the change.

I tested all buttons and shapes, none seem to work:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bookmarks only preserve the "Data state" (ie filters, slicers, selections) and/or "Visual state" (ie if a visual is visibile or not).

To achieve what you are looking for, you will need two buttons, one of each colour. Then using the Selection pane, hide one show the other for one bookmark, then switch them round for the other bookmark.